# Unable to prepare route [password/reset] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [password.request]

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have created a small application in Laravel 8. Everything is fine, but when I wanted to configure the cache I had an error that one route has the same name as another.

Reviewing the routes I found duplicate named routes, but since I'm new to Laravel, I don't know how to solve this problem. I do not know what to do to have two routes with the same name I hope you can guide me a bit.

[image: Screenshot output of php artisan route:list]

Comment: Why do you want to have two routes with same name? if you used `route('routeName')` how laravel will know which action to dispatch. Rename the route names will solve the issue. Did you try to give each route a different name?

Comment: Those routes were generated when you installed the laravel authentication package. As I'm new to this, I don't know what happened. I realized how much I wanted to optimize laravel, it's as if I had two authentication packages. Because those routes cannot be found routes/wep.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the laravel auth routes

```
Route::post('password/email', [
    'as' => 'laravel.password.email',
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail'
]);

Route::get('password/reset', [
    'as' => 'laravel.password.request',
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm'
]);
```

But dont forget to change the old route names

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 7, applications usually call `Auth::routes();` in their `routes/web.php` file. This registers routes defined by package [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) for various user authentication features.

Search your application's route files in `routes/*.php` for routes mentioned in the error message, like `password.email` and `password.request`.

Rename your custom routes to a different route name, then update that route name throughout your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `->except('show')` on the duplicate route worked for me.